# Is it possible to redirect back to a POST or PUT request URL after a successful SAML SSO assertion?

Tags: authentication, redirect, http-post, single-sign-on, saml

I have read about the `relayState` parameter in SAML SSO, and how the SP can redirect the user back to the original incoming URL by making use of `relayState`, but to my knowledge HTTP redirect only works for GET requests.

I am wondering if the same can be done for POST, PUT and DELETE requests, considering these requests usually come with data in the request body as well. I thought of returning a self-submitting form for POST requests, but this won't work for any other HTTP verb, and the original request must be a form based request too, unless the framework supports treating all types of parameters (query string, form field, json element) similarly. I also thought of making the frontend reconstruct the original request and sending it back to SP with AJAX, but I'm not sure if AJAX can actually update the browser's current page address.

My compromise solution in the end was to only relay URLs that result in a whole new page rendering with a GET verb only, and for any other requests, use the referrer URL for relaying instead. This means for the latter, the user will have to perform the task manually again after landing on the page he last saw before the SSO flow.

Not sure what the common practice in the industry is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you would to maintain / save the POST data on the SP end and re-use them after SAML flow succeed. SAML as such does not provide any mean to achieve this.

Comment: Surely I can save all the information about an incoming request at the SP, but eventually it is the browser that must issue the request once again. If current frontend technologies don't even allow POST or PUT redirect then I don't think what I'm trying to do is the right approach? What's the common approach like? Do you guys only handle GET redirect?